# How to use LINQ with DropDownList

Tags: c#, linq, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>once</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>twice</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>thrice</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1/22/2014</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1/25/2016</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

How can I set up LINQ to do the following:

- If Any of the selected index is greater than 0 then use the condition otherwise select all.

I did the following:

```
GridView1.DataSource = List1
    .Where(en => 
        en.howManyTimes == (dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex > 0 ? dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value : ""))
    .Select(en => new { en.TheID, en.GetFile, en.GetLink });
```

I am just not sure after the `:` in the ternary operator.

This is what I would like:

> GridView1.DataSource = List1.Where(en => en.howManyTimes == (if
>   dropdownlist1 selected index is great than 0 then use that value for
>   howManyTimes, otherwise select any howManyTimes) &&  en.whatDate ==
>   (if dropdownlist2 selected index is great than 0 then use that value
>   for whatDate, otherwise select any whatDate)).Select(en => new {
>   en.TheID, en.GetFile, en.GetLink });

Can I please get some assistance in completing it.

Comment: I wanted to put all them in one LINQ query but I don't think that's possible huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Any of the selected index is greater than 0 then use the condition otherwise select all.

You can achieve this by making the predicate evaluate to something that's always true when `dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex <= 0`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = List1
    .Where(en => dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex <= 0
              || en.howManyTimes == dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value)
    .Select(en => new { en.TheID, en.GetFile, en.GetLink });
```

Comment: That might work. Thanks for the post. So would having another dropdownlist be added with another `||`, or easier and recommended to have multiple `Where()`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *having another dropdownlist*. Please try if this works for you first. Then try if you can get *another dropdownlist* working and ask a new question if you need additional help.

Comment: Actually It is still part of the same question :). It seems to be working but another condition for the second dropdown didn't work correctly. I updated my question with your code updated with mine...

Comment: Nevermind... I just used multiple `Where` and it worked. Thanks for the help.